# Filter a dataframe's string values based on a smaller string they might contain

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with log error messages. The column we need looks something like this:

```
message
 
"System error foo"  
"System error foo2"    
"System error foo"    
"System error foo"   
"System error foo3"
```

I need to count all error messages, doesn't matter what kind of error they are.

Usually, if I knew a specific message, I'd filter a dataframe like this:

```
df2 = df[df['message'] == 'System error foo3.']
```

But how can I do this with all the messages that just contain "System error" plus whatever else goes after it? I tried it with the asterix, but it didn't work of course. Is there some sort of python or pandas native wildcard operator? Or do I need to use regex?

Comment: `df[df['message'].str.contains('System error')]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=["System Error foo 1","System Error bar 2","System Error foo3","Error bar"],columns=["messages"])
>>> df
             messages
0  System Error foo 1
1  System Error bar 2
2   System Error foo3
3           Error bar
>>> df[df['messages'].str.contains('System Error')]
             messages
0  System Error foo 1
1  System Error bar 2
2   System Error foo3
```